# Dynamic image view size

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Can I get an image view to dynamically change size (ignore the potential picture quality issues) when a navigation controllers navigationbar or toolbar is hidden/not hidden?

I would prefer using storyboard settings if possible.

Comment: Apply constraints to the image view so it fills it's parent view.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate? I tried setting constraints but the navigation bar just slides on top/above of the picture.